# Dealing with IBM Doors

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

There's two tags right now

[dxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dxl)

> DXL (DOORS Extension Language) is a scripting language for IBM Rational DOORS.

And [doors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/doors)

> Rational Dynamic Object Oriented Requirements System (DOORS) is a requirement management tool and has its own programming language called DOORS eXtension Language (DXL). Rational DOORS Next Generation is now developed on the IBM Jazz platform.

These should be synonyms of one another. So I would like to suggest

1. Synonym [dxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dxl) to [doors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/doors)
2. Rename [doors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/doors) to [ibm-doors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-doors) for consistency

Comment: or maybe 1. rename `doors` to `ibm-doors` 2. synonym `dxl` to `ibm-doors`?